How to install Android SDK extension from Android 15 Beta?
I want to test new functionality, that included in Android 15 Beta
This functionality marked in documentation like that:
Added in API level 35
Also in S Extensions 13

I want to install this Extension 13 (as it allows to use added functionality on older Android versions), but I can't see it in SDK Manager (in Canary Android LadyBug either), just Android SDK Platform 35 and Android SDK Platform 34-ext12
Why is that? Is it expected to appear after Android 15 release?

Yes, that is correct, from past Android releases the extension version only comes out after the stable release. Hopefully by next month.

It's interesting. Currently there is no extension 13, but I can see extension 35-ext14 )

@sergiytykhonov extension 13 came out with Android 15 when it was released back in October, also was there in the Android 15 preview. But Google didn't release this to devices less than API level 35. Extension 14 came in November. Google didn't release emulator image for extension 35-ext13, but if you did adb shell getprop | grep build.version.extensions on a Android 15 without November play system update you can see extension 13. Anyways with extension 14 you are getting everything from 13.
